# Validate if string is list of integers separated by one comma in C

Tags: c

I need to write a function that gets a string of integers or symbols separated by **exactly one comma** between each element and validate that this is the case for a project of mine. Also, between each element, there can be an unlimited number of whitespace, and having a comma at the beginning or end is not allowed as well.

**valid strings example:**

```
"6, -9, 10"
" 3,    5, len"
```

**not valid strings example:**

```
,6 ,7 ,6
10, 4, , 3
3, len, 4,
```

I have been trying for ages to come up with an algorithm that does that. Can someone help me do it?

Comment: len is not an integer

Comment: I'd be lazy and use a regular expression.

Comment: @Shawn: That is overkill; the problem is satisfied by a simple finite state machine.

Comment: yea len is not an integer but it can be a symbol in the program

Comment: Naive solution: write a function to split your string into an array of substrings, splitting on `,`, then validate that each is either an integer constant or a symbol as a second step?

Comment: I already tried it but it will split by more then one occurance of the ','. so it will not work for situations where there is two commas between each integers: ```1,,4,5```

Comment: You must have a more formal definition of what can or can not be a _"symbol in the program"_ . Do you mean the exact term `len` is ok? Just this one beyond numbers? And for numbers, only integers, so no decimal point? Up to how many digits? zero is ok? zeros at the left are ok? Do you only want only to validate, not to upload the sequence to some structure?

Comment: @roee sounds like you need to massage that to give you empty (or space-filled) substrings when more than one comma occurs between numbers or symbols.

Comment: "`valid strings example:`" contains "`, 10\n 3,`", perhaps suggesting `\n` is a separator (equivalent to an actual comma.) The provided (poor) examples are insufficient to assess the constraints of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily performed by a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

I assume a “symbol” is an identifier starting with a letter and containing only letters and digits.

You only need five states:

- Before—the initial state, before we see any digit or letter.
- HaveSign—a hyphen (for a minus sign) has just been seen.
- InNumeral—we have seen at least one digit and are parsing a numeral.
- InName—we have seen at least one letter and are parsing a symbol name.
- After—we have seen spaces after a numeral or a name.

Write code:

- Start a declaration for a routine that will return 1 or 0 to indicate if a string is accepted or not.
- Write a loop that calls `getchar` to get the next character and exits if `EOF` is returned. (You might also want to exit if a new-line character is returned, depending on how the end of the string is indicated.)
- Inside the loop, test whether the character is a space, a comma, a hyphen, a digit, a letter, or none of those.

  - For each character case, consider each state:

    - Can this character validly occur in this state? If not, return from the routine with non-acceptance.
    - If this character can occur, what should the next state be? Set the state to that and continue the outer loop, to read the next character.
- After the loop, what states are valid to end with? If the state is valid, return from the routine with acceptance. Otherwise, return with non-acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

If the individual substrings between commas are important beyond simply validating the string, you will need to manage a dynamically allocated array of strings, since you cannot know the needed size unless you pre-count the commas.

You can run a loop:

- If necessary, reallocate the array to expand it.
- You can get a pointer to the next delimiter (if one exists) with [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).
- If there is no next delimiter, push the remainder of the original string onto your array and break the loop.
- If there is, use pointer math to figure out how long the substring is.
- Allocate a sufficiently long string onto the end of the array and copy from the front of the string the current segment.
- Update the current "front" of the string.

You'll also need to update a variable indicating how many substrings you found.

The next important step is to build a function which can strip the whitespace from a string. You can use a forward and a reverse loop to determine which substring to return to strip leading and trailing whitespace.

Once you have accomplished both of these things you can iterate over these strings to validate, and you'll have those substrings for further use without any extra work.